# Ls with spaces + variables

Tags: bash, ls, pipe, control-flow

I want to do something like this, but it doesn't save the variable after the piping ends:

```
fs=( )
echo ${fs[@]}
ls -A1 |
while read f
do
    echo ${fs[@]}
    fs+=( "$f" )
    echo ${fs[@]}
done
echo "All files/dirs: "${fs[@]}
```

With files 1, 2 and 3 in the current dir I get this output:

```
# Output:


1
1
1 2
1 2
1 2 3
All files/dirs:
```

How do I keep the fs variable's value, after the piping ends?

**Update:**

- Can't use *, becuase i need hidden files
- Can't just use fs=($(ls)),
  while sometimes the file/dir names will have spaces in them

Answer (score 12, accepted):

[Don't parse the output of `ls`.](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs)

The way to list all the files in a directory in the shell is simply `*`.

```
for f in *; do …
```

In shells with array support (bash, ksh, zsh), you can directly assign the file list to an array variable: `fs=(*)`

This omits dot files, which goes against your use of `ls -A`. In bash, set the `dotglob` option first to include dot files, and set `nullglob` to have an empty array if the current directory is empty:

```
shopt -s dotglob nullglob
fs=(*)
```

In ksh, use `FIGNORE=".?(.)"; fs=(~(N)*)`. In zsh, use the `D` and `N` glob qualifiers: `fs=(*(DN))`. In other shells, this is more difficult; your best bet is to include each of the patterns `*` (non-dot files), `.[!.]*` (single-dot files, not including `.` and double-dot files) and `..?*` (double-dot files, not including `..` itself), and check each for emptiness.

```
set -- *; [ -e "$1" ] || shift
set .[!.]* "$@"; [ -e "$1" ] || shift
set ..?* "$@"; [ -e "$1" ] || shift
for x; do …  # short for for x in "$@"; do …
```

---

I'd better explain what was going wrong in your attempt, too. The main problem is that each side of a pipe runs in a subprocess, so the assignments to `fs` in the loop are taking place in a subprocess and never passed on to the parent process. (This is the case in most shells, including bash; the two exceptions are ATT ksh and zsh, where the right-hand side of a pipeline runs in the parent shell.) You can observe this by launching an external subprocess and arranging for it to print its parent's process ID¹´²:

```
sh -c 'echo parent: $PPID'
{ sh -c 'echo left: $PPID >/dev/tty'; echo $? >/dev/null; } |
{ sh -c 'echo right: $PPID >/dev/tty'; echo $? >/dev/null; }
```

In addition, your code had two reliability problems:

- [Don't parse the output of `ls`.](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs)
- `read` mangles whitespace and backslashes; to parse lines, you need `while IFS= read -r line; do …`

For those times when you do need to parse lines and use the result, put the whole data processing in a block.

```
producer … | {
  while IFS= read -r line; do
    …
  done
  consumer
}
```

¹ 
<sub>Note that `$$` wouldn't show anything: it's the process ID of the main shell process, it doesn't change in subshells.</sub>

² 
<sub>In some bash versions, if you just call `sh` on a side of the pipe, you might see the same process ID, because bash optimizes a call to an external process. The fluff with the braces and `echo $?` defeat this optimization.</sub>

Comment: One last thing: if I normally wanted to use `sudo ls -A1` to grab the files, how would I do that with the *?

Comment: I want to list the files in a partition's .Trashes folder (/Volumes/External HD/.Trashes/), which requires root priviledges.

Comment: @Tyilo: Hmm, tricky. Bash doesn't support null characters in general, but `sudo bash -c 'shopt -s nullglob dotglob; printf "%s\\0" *' | while IFS= read -r -d "" filename; do …` seems to work (using a null character as the separator, this way all file names work).

Comment: The way to remove the pipeline and hence remove the subshell (and keep the variable in the current shell) is to use process substitution: `while IFS= read -r -d "" filename; do f+=("$filename"); done < <(shopt -s nullglob dotglob; printf "%s\\0" *)` -- this also keeps the shopt in a subshell.

Answer (score -2):

This code will do you want you want-

```
#!/bin/sh
echo *
```

What exactly are you trying to do here?

You can also do

```
var=*
echo $var
```

If you need more than that, I recommend you go to stackoverflow.

Comment: This doesn't appear to answer the question at all, if I'm understanding it correctly. In any case, you shouldn't post answers just because you lack the rep for a comment, and definitely don't tell people to go to SO for their completely on-topic questions

Comment: It is a potential answer but the asker rulled it out already based on needing more features than just globbing. @Michael's other points stand, don't post question clarification comments in answers and don't send people off-site for on-topic issues.

Comment: Thats all fine and valid, I just don't think it should've been deleted. Furthermore, I posted this answer -before- he updated his post.

Answer (score -3):

Do you really need the pipe? You can easily do it with for:

```
fs=( )
echo ${fs[@]}
for file in `ls`
do
        echo $file
        fs+=$file
done
echo $fs
echo "All files/dirs: "${fs[@]}
```

Comment: `\`ls\`` will choke horribly on file names containing whitespace, unprintable characters, or shell wildcards. Don't do this.