# How to convert TXT to PDF?

Tags: text-processing, pdf, imagemagick, conversion

I want to convert `.txt` files to `.pdf`. I'm using this:

```
ls | while read ONELINE; do convert -density 400 "$ONELINE" "$(echo "$ONELINE" | sed 's/.txt/.pdf/g')"; done
```

But this produces one "error" -- if there's a very long line in the text file, it doesn't get wrapped.

#### Input text

[image: Screenshot of the input file]

#### Output PDF

[image: Screenshot of the output PDF]

--

Also, it would also be great if the output PDF could contain text, instead of images of text.

I have many-many-many TXT files. So don't want to do it by hand. I need an automatic solution, like the one I mentioned above.

Comment: You should use `for ONELINE in *` instead of `ls | while read ONELINE`. Read [this](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/17005/26112).

Comment: I don't have enough rep to answer, but i just want to add that the Kate editor in KDE kubuntu you can print to PDF "printer" which lets you select filename and it produces a .pdf.

Comment: Cross-site link: same question on AskUbuntu [How to print a regular file to pdf from command line - Ask Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/27097/how-to-print-a-regular-file-to-pdf-from-command-line)

Answer (score 27, accepted):

One method is to use CUPS and the PDF psuedo-printer to "print" the text to a PDF file.

Another is to use [enscript](http://www.gnu.org/software/enscript/enscript.html) to encode to postscript and then convert from postscript to PDF using the ps2pdf file from ghostscript package.

Comment: thanks.: http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=XQnRjtnR

Comment: doesn anybody has UTF-8 support for enscript?

Comment: @LanceBaynes [Cedilla](http://www.pps.jussieu.fr/~jch/software/repos/cedilla/), or [gnome-u2ps](http://bonobo.gnome.gr.jp/~nakai/u2ps/), or [u2ps](http://u2ps.berlios.de/).

Answer (score 58):

[pandoc](http://johnmacfarlane.net/pandoc/) can do this. It's more focused on converting marked-up text to various formats, but it should have no problems with simple plaintext.

```
pandoc input.txt -o output.pdf
```

Comment: Looks nice, but the massive amount of haskell dependencies pandoc wants scared me away :/

Comment: @Ikraav yeah, it's way overkill for this purpose, but if you have markdown or HTML (or any of the other markups it can accept as input) pandoc would be the way to go. PDF actually requires even more dependencies -- internally, pandoc uses LaTeX to convert to PDF, so you need to install that stuff too -- but the quality is very good (I use it to convert markdown'd text to PDF and EPUB, primarily).

Comment: pandoc (1.16.0.2) replaces my newlines with tabs.

Comment: Pandoc will default to Markdown. For a general plain-text this will fail.

Comment: This removes new-lines and dramatically changes formatting.

Comment: Completely useless results. It squeezed things in a column of 10 chars wide?! And all newlines were removed.

Comment: @CarloWood, here (Fedora 37, pandoc-2.14.0.3-18.fc37.x86_64) I get no such results.

Answer (score 32):

You can print text to a PostScript file using Vim and then convert it to a PDF, as long as Vim was compiled with the `+postscript` feature.

For this you use the `:hardcopy > {filename}` command. For example you can open `example.txt` and execute

```
:hardcopy > example.ps
```

which will produce a file `example.ps` containing all the text in `example.txt`. The header of each page in the PostScript file will contain the original filename and the page number.

Then you can convert the PostScript file into a PDF by using the following command

```
ps2pdf example.ps
```

which will create `example.pdf`.

You can do the same directly from a terminal (without interacting with Vim) by using the following command

```
vim example.txt -c "hardcopy > example.ps | q"; ps2pdf example.ps
```

This opens `example.txt` in Vim and executes the command passed to the `-c` option, which in this case is a `hardcopy` command followed by a quit (`q`) command. Then it executes `ps2pdf` to produce the final file.

<sub>For more options see the help files with `:help :hardcopy`.</sub>

Comment: `:hardcopy` produces a PostScript file no matter I add .pdf or .ps extensions. I did `:hardcpy > example.pdf` and with `less example.pdf` in shell I could see that the file header was `%!PS-Adobe-3.0`.

Comment: @taro, you are correct. At the time I wrote this I didn't notice that. I updated my answer. The final command could be improved, but I can't write that right now. Might do it later.

Comment: Note that this does not support UTF-8. Looks like a call to `enscript`.

Comment: More about UTF-8 printing: [encoding - Printing unicode chars? - Vi and Vim Stack Exchange](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/12058/printing-unicode-chars)  // [syntax highlighting - How to change Vim's :hardcopy printfont? - Vi and Vim Stack Exchange](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/6913/how-to-change-vims-hardcopy-printfont)

Answer (score 22):

LibreOffice / OpenOffice as well as most other word processors (Abiword) can do this quite easily.

There is a little utility called `unoconv` that uses the LibreOffice code base to do file format conversions on the command line. It can read and write any combination of formats that LibreOffice can and makes it very easy to do things like `doc` to `pdf` conversions on the command line. Simple `txt` to `pdf` would be easy for it.

Comment: Interesting. Didn't know about `unoconv` and didn't even know OO had APIs.

Comment: Produces high quality results, but, for me (I'm using version 0.5-1 (Debian Wheezy)), I have to first run a `unoconv --listener &` command.

Comment: Any example commands you can provide?

Answer (score 20):

LibreOffice works for this. Usage:

`libreoffice --convert-to "pdf" file.txt`

The output will be called `file.pdf`.

Comment: Is there a way to change font size in the resulting PDF?

Comment: @Evg I do not know of a way to do so with this method of using LibreOffice.

Comment: this only works for me

Comment: quicker: `unoconv file.txt`. calling the same libreoffice.

Comment: Thanks. I did not know about that. I just tried it, and it works very nicely.

Comment: libreoffice command not found

Comment: @chovy It works for me on Debian 11. Either you do not have it installed, or your distro's version does not have that command associated with LibreOffice.

Comment: i had to reload zsh

Answer (score 13):

Just use the [text2pdf](http://www.eprg.org/pdfcorner/text2pdf/) , which is free and opensource.
At the link you can download the source or the pre-compiled binary for windows, solaris, dos.

I'm able to use it into AIX OS without problem.
Very simple to compile , just save the text2pdf.c and Makefile into the same directory and type `make`. (here I set the variable CC=gcc on AIX, on linux this will not be an issue)

```
$ ./text2pdf  -h

text2pdf [options] [filename]

  text2pdf makes a 7-bit clean PDF file (version 1.1) from any input file.
  It reads from standard input or a named file, and writes the PDF file
  to standard output.

  There are various options as follows:

  -h            show this message
  -f<font>      use PostScript <font> (must be in standard 14, default: Courier)
  -I            use ISOLatin1Encoding
  -s<size>      use font at given pointsize (default 10)
  -v<dist>      use given line spacing (default 12 points)
  -l<lines>     lines per page (default 60, determined automatically
                if unspecified)
  -c<chars>     maximum characters per line (default 80)
  -t<spaces>    spaces per tab character (default 8)
  -F            ignore formfeed characters (^L)
  -A4           use A4 paper (default Letter)
  -A3           use A3 paper (default Letter)
  -x<width>     independent paper width in points
  -y<height>    independent paper height in points
  -2            format in 2 columns
  -L            landscape mode

  Note that where one variable is implied by two options, the second option
  takes precedence for that variable. (e.g. -A4 -y500)
  In landscape mode, page width and height are simply swapped over before
  formatting, no matter how or when they were defined.

text2pdf v1.1 (c) Phil Smith, 1996
$ ./text2pdf  -f"Courier" -s6 -c216 -v6 -L -A4 ./rep3.txt >rep3.pdf
```

Comment: is there an utf8 capable fork of this?

Comment: @WolfgangFahl Alas, this program is not legally forkable "as is", as the file header says: "You may not alter the source in any way [...] without the permission of the author, Phil Smith <phil@bagobytes.co.uk>"

Comment: @WolfgangFahl Alas, this program is not legally forkable "as is", as the file header says: "You may not alter the source in any way [...] without the permission of the author, Phil Smith <phil@bagobytes.co.uk>". This program is compiling & working on my Linux, but is from 1996 and generates PDF file version 1.1. It is fast though.

Comment: For UTF-8 encoding, I am going to use puppeteer for Node.js.

Answer (score 11):

There is also a UTF-8 to PostScript converter called [`paps`](http://sourceforge.net/projects/paps/).

Comment: It works, and with TrueType fonts, but it should be noted that it produces a document with bitmaps as a result, instead of using the fonts natively. (I guess that's because of Postscript?)

Comment: Couldn't compile it on Cygwin32 on my Windoze...

Comment: Not too simple, not too complicated. It will read from stdin, for example `pr -e3 -t test.txt | paps`

Answer (score 8):

Use enscript to created a .ps file, and then ps2pdf (or ps2pdfwr) to convert to .pdf

The following script creates a .pdf file with 10 pt left and right margins, and uses a courier font that is 7.3 pts wide and 10 pts high, so a 132 col printout fits on an 8 1/2 X 11 page.  Use enscript to setup your page, fonts, etc.

```
$ enscript -B --margins=10:10: -o outputfile.ps -f Courier@7.3/10 inputfile
$ ps2pdfwr outputfile.ps newfile.pdf
$ rm outputfile.ps
```

Comment: A thing to note: enscript does not support utf-8.

Comment: Without utf-8, that means no Chinese characters, etc.. Going to use puppeteer for this.

Answer (score 3):

Since it's included by default in many distributions, a shorter way to call `libreoffice` from the cli:

```
soffice --convert-to pdf input.txt
```

Supported extensions by `soffice`, we can convert from/to:

```
ODF Spreadsheet                   .ods
ODF Spreadsheet Template          .ots
Flat XML ODF Spreadsheet          .fods
Unified Office Format Spreadsheet .uos
Microsoft Excel 2007-2013 XML     .xlsx
Microsoft Excel 2003 XML          .xml
Microsoft Excel 97-2003           .xls
Microsoft Excel 97-2003 Template  .xlt
Data Interchange Format           .dif
dBase                             .dbf
HTML Document (Calc)              .html
SYLK                              .slk
Text CSV                          .csv
Office Open XML Spreadsheet       .xlsx
Microsoft Excel 2007-2016 XML     .xlsm
```

Answer (score 3):

I am adding this `a2ps` as another alternative. `a2ps` produces postscript file, then could be converted into pdf using `ps2pdf`. Both `a2ps` and `ps2pdf` should be in the major Linux distros repository.

```
a2ps input.txt -o output.ps
ps2pdf output.ps output.pdf
```

Comment: May have problems with some apostrophe characters, but probably easy to fix with search/replace.

Answer (score 1):

Easiest way using `calibre`

- install (on `.deb`-based distributions):

  ```
  sudo apt-get install calibre
  ```
- then run:

  ```
  ebook-convert /path/to/input.txt path/to/ouput.pdf
  ```

Comment: My apologies, what I meant with "*" is any name, but now I get it this wildcard could be translated to multiple inputs, I'm going to edit it now.

Comment: Ok, then I understand the original intention. The edit really helps to clarify!

Answer (score 0):

It is also possible to wrap the text from the input text file into a helper Latex document:

```latex
\documentclass{letter}
\begin{document}
\input{input.txt}  % text file with the input text
\end{document}
```

and then compile it directly to PDF using `pdflatex`:

```bash
$ pdflatex helper.tex
```