# Print pdf like paps, but with actual fonts?

Tags: pdf, conversion, text

So I convert a piece of text to PDF like so:

```
INPUT="this text goes to a pdf file"
paps $INPUT 2>/dev/null | ps2pdf -sPAPERSIZE=a4 -dOptimize=true -dEmbedAllFonts=true - out.pdf
```

Which works great, were it not for the very annoying fact that the produced PDF is *an image* -- meaning the text can't be selected or searched. I searched for alternatives, but I could not find one that allows the font to be changed (which `paps` does). In particular, the alternatives given [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/17406/how-to-convert-txt-to-pdf) are not suitable, for one reason or another (lack of UTF-8 support, etc.).

Is there a tool that fulfils the aforementioned requirements?

Comment: It's been a while since I've looked at the output of latex-based ps & the resulting pdf's but that's another option.

Answer (score 0):

There is a new version of paps that is able to write selectable pdf directly. See: https://github.com/dov/paps