# How can I save output of my script to different directory in txt or pdf format

Tags: system-programming

`clear
echo "testing calc"
date
echo -e "======================================"
yc1=0
yc2=0
yc3=0
lol=0
tnd=0
lno=0
c1=0
c1b=0
c2=0
c2b=0
c3=0
c3b=0
bb=12
wt=100
con=768
rip=0
sw=0
echo ""
echo ""
echo -n "Please Enter Lot no.           = "
read lno

numeric=0;
while
[ $numeric -eq 0 ] ;
do read -p "Please Enter Total Ends        = " tnd ;
if [[ $tnd =~ ^[0-9]+$ ]] ;
then
numeric=1 ;
else echo "Error: No's Only, 4 Digits" ;
fi ;
done
echo ""

numeric=0;
while
[ $numeric -eq 0 ] ;
do read -p "Please Enter 1st Count         = " yc1 ;
if [[ $yc1 =~ ^[0-9]+$ ]] ;
then
numeric=1 ;
else echo "Error: No's Only, 2 Digits" ;
fi ;
done

numeric=0;
while
[ $numeric -eq 0 ] ;
do read -p "Please Enter Cones per Bag     = " c1b ;
if [[ $c1b =~ ^[0-9]+$ ]] ;
then
numeric=1 ;
else echo "Error: No's Only, 2 Digits" ;
fi ;
done

numeric=0;
while
[ $numeric -eq 0 ] ;
do read -p "Please Enter $((yc1))/s Count %      = " c1 ;
if [[ $c1 =~ ^[0-9]+$ ]] ;
then
numeric=1 ;
else echo "Error: No's Only, 2 or 3 Digits" ;
fi ;
done

echo -e "$(($c1))% Ends for $((yc1))/s Count        = $(($tnd * $c1 / $wt))"
y1a=$(($bb * $c1 / $wt))
echo -e "No of Beam for $((yc1))/s Count      = $y1a"
echo -e "Ends per Beam                  = $((($tnd * $c1 / $wt) / ($bb * $c1 / $wt)))"
y1b=$(($yc1 * $(($wt / $c1b)) * $con))
echo -e "Lenght of $((yc1))/s Count Cone      = $y1b"
echo ""
`
This is part of a script.
**What I want is the output of the script should be saved on different directory in txt or pdf format in below mentioned form.**

testing calculator

### Sat Mar  5 02:44:16 EST 2016

Lot no.         = 4566    Total Ends      = 4800    Lenght of Lot   = 12000

1st Count       = 16
Count %         = 100
Ends for Count  = 4800
No of Beam      = 12
Ends per Beam   = 400
Lenght of Cone  = 49152 
Beams per Creel = 4 
Creels Required = 3

## Bags Required   = 50

------------------          ------------------
Man. XXXXXXXX               Man. XXXXXXX

Comment: ...along with [how to convert text to pdf](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/17406/how-to-convert-txt-to-pdf)

Comment: I beleive that i asked too much from you guys. admit it ...... you cant handle this question.

Comment: Your question is closed and therefore cannot be answered. In order for others to be able to answer the question, you'll need to request that it be reopened. However, note that it won't be reopened unless you've improved the question. Although you have edited the question, it still doesn't give anyone any more information about what you need, and would probably not be considered an improvement.  Maybe an example or two would help for a start and maybe explain what part of redirecting to a file you don't understand.

Answer (score 1):

Using the `>` redirect function, you can send the output of any script or command into a file at any location.  By default, the file is created in the present working directory, but you can specify an absolute or relative path to the file if you wish:

```
/usr/local/bin/somescript.sh > /path/to/Documents/someprogram.log
```

Comment: This is only creating an empty file to my desired location not the output of my script.

Comment: That will be the case if your script is not producing any output.  If you want to also capture standard error in addition to standard output, rather than `>` use `> 2>&1`.

Answer (score 0):

For pdf you can send the output of you program to text2pdf
`<your script> | text2pdf -o <somepath-to-other-dir>/output.pdf`