# Traverse all subdirectories in and do something in Unix shell script

Tags: bash, shell-script

I want my shell script to visit all subdirectories in a main directory. Do something in directories, sent output to a spool file and move on to next directory.
Consider 
Main Dir = /tmp
Sub Dir = A B C D (Four sub directories)

Comment: OK, please show us your script so far. Which part of it is giving you trouble?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the solution. The find command below meets my requirements.

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -type d \( ! -name . \) -exec bash -c "cd '{}' && ls -l |awk '{ print $9 }' |grep `date +"%m%d%Y"`|xargs echo" \;
```

Answer (score 36):

Use a `for` loop:

```
for d in $(find /path/to/dir -maxdepth 1 -type d)
do
  #Do something, the directory is accessible with $d:
  echo $d
done >output_file
```

It searches only the subdirectories of the directory `/path/to/dir`. Note that the simple example above will fail if the directory names contain whitespace or special characters. A safer approach is:

```
find /tmp -maxdepth 1 -type d -print0 |
  while IFS= read -rd '' dir; do echo "$dir"; done
```

---

Or in plain `bash`:

```sh
for d in /path/to/dir/*; do
  if [ -d "$d" ]; then
    echo "$d"
  fi
done
```

(note that contrary to `find` that one also considers symlinks to directories and excludes hidden ones)

Comment: at least point the limitations and risks associated with processing the output of `find` like that.

Comment: Hi...i tried to run below for loop

for d in $(find /backup/ASHISH -maxdepth 1 -type d)
do
   ls -l |awk '{ print $9 }' |grep CC*_`date +"%m%d20%Y"`|xargs echo
  echo $d

Comment: Hi...
I tried below for loop.

for d in $(find /backup/ASHISH -maxdepth 1 -type d)
do
   ls -l |awk '{ print $9 }' |grep CC*_`date +"%m%d20%Y"`|xargs echo
  echo $d

The expected outcome is ls -ltr from all subdirectory. Above loop not working

Answer (score 2):

I am a complete `bash` newbie, but a UN*X veteran.  Although doubtless this can be done in Bash shell scripting, in the old days we used `find [-maxdepth <levels>] <start-dir> -exec <command> ;` to achieve this.  You could do a `man find` and play around, perhaps until someone tells you how to do it in `bash`!

Comment: I am very flattered that my "outline" answer here has received an up-vote.  However, why has @chaos' answer below received a down-vote? (As a newcomer to this board, I cannot post this comment against his answer, only against my own.)  His second suggestion is correct for a shell script solution, and avoids the overhead of running an external `find` command.

Comment: His second is indeed correct. His first will fail if the directory names contain whitespace or special characters (backslashes for example). See the edit I made to his answer for the safe version.

Comment: I agree.  It was his second, shell-only answer I was praising.

Comment: I know, I was just explaining the downvote (which I did not cast).

Comment: I did cast it. The [`$(find...)` thing is _bad practice_](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs).

Answer (score 2):

Looks like you want the filenames under each of the subdirs; the `ls -l | awk` is not robust enough, for what if those filenames comprise whitespace and/or newlines? The below `find` would work even for `find`s that donot happen to have the `-maxdepth` going for them:

```
find . ! -name . -type d -prune -exec sh -c '
   cd "$1" && \
   find "." ! -name . -prune  -type f
' {} {} \;
```

Answer (score 1):

It's also possible using ls, grep, and tr

```
for dir in $(ls -1FA | grep / | tr -d /); do echo $dir/something; done

ls -1FA | grep / | tr -d / | while IFS= read -r TD; do echo $TD/something; done
```

du/sed can also be used as a selector if your ls lacks the above options

```
du --max-depth=1 | sed -e 's/^.*\.\///' | grep -v '\.$'
```

It may be important to note these examples return hidden directories and exclude parent and current directories

Comment: (1) `ls` writes one file per line (what the `-1` option specifies) by default when the standard output is a pipe (so it’s superfluous in your answers). (2) Parsing the output of `ls` is a bad idea — see [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/16993/23408#17005) and [this](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs).  Your first answer will fail if directories have spaces (or newlines) in their names, and all will fail if they have newlines in their names. (3) You should always quote shell variables (e.g., ```"$dir"```) unless you have a good reason not to, and you’re sure you know what you’re doing.

Comment: Good points Scott. Leaving the answer as, for many systems without egregiously-named dirs, I think it may be still useful for the one offs.